# How do I automatically remove nonstandard elements from fields in a .csv file? (see description)

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, contacts

I have an enormous contacts file in .CSV format with about 15,200 entries. Many entries are nonstandard, repeating the email address in the first name field or something like this. I want to automatically remove all of these nonstandard entries and leave all the ones that have a First and last name and an email address in their appropriate fields. How do you do this?

Comment: Downvote. Question too vague without including at least a few example rows. "repeating the email address in the first name field or something like this" is not a lot to go on... Please don't make people *guess* what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The Long winded way of doing this would be to open the document in excel,

1) Highlight the column with first name and select Find & replace.

Find what: (asterix)*@*(asterix)
Replace with:          (leave this blank)

then select Replace All,

This will clear all results that are email addresses in the first name box.

2) Now select your whole data and sort by first name, this should leave all your blanks at the bottom, feel free to delete all those rows without any data in the first name box.

[EDIT] - I see that you wanted an automated way of doing this however, if this is only a one off job, this route would probably be quicker than designing & creating a Macro to do it. If you plan on doing this act multiple times then maybe a long term solution would be to create a macro.